# Как одновременно с помощью наушников слушать то, что на экране ноутбука, чтобы динамики озвучивали то, что на втором экране, на мониторе?

Tags: ноутбук

Как наушниками слушать на экране ноутбука, чтобы динамики озвучивали то что на втором экране?

Comment: Звук никак не привязан к экранам. Заглядывайте в настройки звука в используемых вами приложениях для выбора конкретного устройства вывода звука.

Comment: Спасибо. Я понимаю. Но если используется одно приложение, например Ютуб, где для ребёнка я включаю что либо детское на телевизоре, а сам на Ютубе смотрю на экране ноутбука.

Comment: Всегда можно запустить два разных ютуба в двух разных браузерах (впрочем, я не помню, бывают ли у браузеров настройки вывода звука)

Comment: Громкость конечно же можно регулировать на разных браузерах. Но насчёт одновременного вывода на наушники и динамики, думаю здесь могут возникнуть проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться утилитой Audio Router она позволяет перенаправлять звук различных приложений на разные аудио устройства. Я так перенаправлял звук с одного из браузеров на HDMI Audio телевизора

https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router

Answer (score 0):

Если монитор (телевизор) подключен по HDMI или DVI-D, то как правило современные видеокарты поддерживают передачу звука по этим портам.
Если это так, то возможно использовать `vlc` плеер, и в расширенных настройках указать вывод звука через определенное устройство, в вашем случае монитор (телевизор). А устройством по умолчанию должна быть звуковая карта с выходом на наушники. Возможно придется использовать два экземпляра `vlc` для разных аудио целей, другими словами, программы проигрывателя без "тонкой" настройки звука могут не подойти.

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Select_from_multiple_audio_devices/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]